# HTTP server returned unexpected status: Internal Server Error

Tags: apache, xml-rpc, bugzilla

I have been using the Lightning Bug API to access Bugzilla via XMLRPC. It had been working fine for the past 10 days but since yesterday, I cannot access the following using the API.
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/xmlrpc.cgi

I can access the bugs of all other projects, except Apache.

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransportException: **HTTP server returned unexpected status: Internal Server Error**
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcCommonsTransport.checkStatus(XmlRpcCommonsTransport.java:259)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcCommonsTransport.getInputStream(XmlRpcCommonsTransport.java:118)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:152)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:143)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:56)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:167)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:137)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:126)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An internal server error means there is a problem with the web application or CGI script your client is communicating with.  So there is nothing you, as the author of the client can do.

Comment: Thank you. I have emailed the admin. Hopefully it will get resolved soon.